# Any known resources for Secured Socket Programming with Jetty?

Tags: security, sockets, ssl, jetty

Do you guys know fine tutorials, sample codes for SSL socket programming with Jetty? I am going to implement some secured applications with Jetty.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Jetty Ssl Socket Connector instead of the often use Socket Connector.
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Ssl+Connector+Guide
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty?focusedCommentId=9241003#comment-9241003

Its not that difficult. Just add the sslSocketConnector to your server (after configuring it) and after this your application should respond to https requests.

```
server.addConnector(sslConnector);
```